# Знак препинания перед риторическим вопросом

Tags: общие-вопросы, пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста. Какие знаки препинания нужно ставить в предложениях такого типа:

А теперь вопрос (?) для чего вам это? - Тире можно поставить? Ведь, наверное, двоеточие нельзя, тогда придется ставить и кавычки.

А теперь задумайтесь (?) зачем вам это? - Тут, я так понимаю, двоеточие поставить можно, так как есть глагол "задумайтесь".

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А теперь вопрос - для чего вам это? А теперь вопрос: для чего вам это?

А теперь задумайтесь - зачем вам это? А теперь задумайтесь: зачем вам это?

В обоих случаях мы имеем БСП, простые предложения связаны изъяснительными отношениями, но в первом случае предложение "А теперь (зададим) вопрос" является неполным.

В данном случае можно ставить и тире, и двоеточие, варианты различаются интонацией. При постановке двоеточия перед вторым предложением делается предупредительная пауза.